# Can we prove Stampacchia theorem by Lax-Milgram theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. A bilinear form $[\cdot, \cdot]:H \times H \to \mathbb R$ is said to be

- *continuous* if there is a constant $C>0$ such that
  $$
  |[u, v]| \le C |u| |v|
  \quad \forall u,v \in H.
  $$
- *coercive* if there is a constant $\alpha>0$ such that
  $$
  [v, v] \ge \alpha |v|^2 
  \quad \forall v \in H.
  $$

Then we have

1. **Stampacchia theorem** Assume that $[\cdot, \cdot]:H \times H \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous coercive bilinear form. Let $K$ be a non-empty closed convex subset of $H$. Then for each $\varphi \in H^*$, there is a unique $u\in K$ such that
   $$
   [u, v-u] \ge \varphi (v-u)
   \quad \forall v\in K.
   $$
   Moreover, if $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is symmetric, then $u$ is characterized as a minimizer of
   $$
   \min_{v\in K} \bigg \{ \frac{1}{2} [v, v] - \varphi (v) \bigg \}.
   $$
2. **Lax-Milgram theorem** Assume that $[\cdot, \cdot]:H \times H \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous coercive bilinear form. Then for each $\varphi \in H^*$, there is a unique $u\in H$ such that
   $$
   [u, v] = \varphi (v)
   \quad \forall v\in H.
   $$
   Moreover, if $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is symmetric, then $u$ is characterized as a minimizer of
   $$
   \min_{v\in H} \bigg \{ \frac{1}{2} [v, v] - \varphi (v) \bigg \}.
   $$

It's straightforward to prove Lax-Milgram theorem by Stampacchia theorem.

> Can we prove Stampacchia theorem by Lax-Milgram theorem?